# Using Timer Control in C# to display call duration in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program which shows the call duration of the call in this format HH:MM:SS, the user may take up another call keeping the current call on hold. Now, do I have to trigger another timer to start from the beginning. I want to use timer control for this to happen, how can I implement this.?

Any other best methods for this.?

Finally I managed to do with the following code.. May be it wil be usefull for others

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    private void MainGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Start();
        timerDuration.Start();
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    private void timerDuration_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
        this.agentView.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = String.Format("{00:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours), elapsed.Minutes, elapsed.Seconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method.

Create a variable to hold the number of elapsed seconds and then one timer. Set its interval to 1000 and subscribe to its `Tick` event.
In the tick event, increase or decrease the time variable as appropriate and call this method to format the time as HH:MM:SS

```
public string GetTime(int Time)
{
    int Hrs = 0;    //number of hours
    int Min = 0;    //number of Minutes
    int Sec = 0;    //number of Sec

    //Seconds
    Sec = Time % 60;

    //Minutes
    Min = ((Time - Sec) / 60) % 60;

    //Hours
    Hrs = ((Time - (Sec + (Min * 60))) / 3600) % 60;

    return Strings.Format(Hrs, "00") + ":" + 
           Strings.Format(Min, "00") + ":" +
           Strings.Format(Sec, "00");
}
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984831/create-a-simple-timer-to-count-seconds-minutes-and-hours/3985770#3985770) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984831) for the VB.NET version.

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating new timers, why one reuse just one ? each new call you can subscribe to OnTick and update the call duration, when you are "on hold" you can unsubscribe.

That scales better if you have number of calls.

if you are not worried about resources, then set interval for your timer to be 1sec, and OnTick event update call duration by one sec.

Timer doesnt run on GUI thread, so you might have to use marshall it back (via InvokeRequired check, SyncContext or Dispatcher).

Comment: @anvarbek : Do i have to increment a variable everytime when the timer ticks? So that i will have each variable for each call?

Comment: New timer for each call - seems to me to be a reasonable approach

Comment: yes, I can't think of better way of using Observer pattern. maybe some other patterns can help you to achieve this better

Comment: @abatishchev : Can you suggest me on how to implement a different timer for each call?

Comment: @anvarbek : Here is the approach i would follow on your suggestion.. I wil have a variable 'callDuration1' for the first call and increment it each second. 'callDuration2' for the second call, we can loop this and create as many calls as we want. Finally for displaying the duration convert the variable in seconds to the required format. Is this okay? If yes , please let me know how to convert the seconds integer to time format HH:MM:SS

Comment: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss") [MSDN link on timespan custom formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Comment: You shouldn't have to increment anything!  Just create a DateTime instance for each call that represents the start time for the call.  Using a single timer, when it ticks, subtract the start time from the current time, which gives a TimeSpan object.  Then use @anvarbek's method to display it.