# how to display time of three textbox in only one label?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void timer_click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    if (seconds == -1)
    {
        minutes = minutes - 1;
        seconds = 59;
    }
    if (minutes == -1)
    {
        hours = hours - 1;
        minutes = 59;
    }
    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
    string hhr = Convert.ToString(hours);
    string minns = Convert.ToString(minutes);
    string seccs = Convert.ToString(seconds);
}
```

I'm trying to create a countdown timer. I am stuck with hhr, minns and seccs because I have to display the countdown in one label not more. How can I pass these three text as hrr:minns:seccs?

Comment: This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619823/5513005) might help you

Comment: you use **string format**, or use **system.timespan**

Comment: var result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", hours, minutes, seconds);

Comment: why not make a function to return like hhr:minns:seccs ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to get the remaining time but here is how you could use the `string.Format` method to display all three components in a single `string`:

```
private void timer_click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    if (seconds == -1)
    {
        minutes = minutes - 1;
        seconds = 59;
    }
    if (minutes == -1)
    {
        hours = hours - 1;
        minutes = 59;
    }
    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
    string hhr = Convert.ToString(hours);
    string minns = Convert.ToString(minutes);
    string seccs = Convert.ToString(seconds);

    string s = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hhr, minns, seccs);
    lbl.Text = s;
}
```

In C#6+ it's even eaiser:

```
string s = $"{hhr}:{minns}:{seccs}";
```

Comment: I think your solution is perfect but the problem is with "RoutedEventArgs". It is supposed to be EventArgs. and the rest is the same

Comment: EventArgs is Windows Forms. RoutedEventArgs is WPF and you tagged the question WPF.