# VB.NET make timer act as a response time base on database data table time

Tags: mysql, vb.net, timer

Okay, Hear me out and then tell me what you think of my problem also any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I'm having a two problem:

1. Attach the "timer" who act as response time in a data that I pulled out in the database table (DB table Screenshot link will be attached at the bottom).
2. Putting it in a button. Let say I have 2 buttons, Start & End when I click Start button then timer start running and when I click End button the response timer and the time data I pulled in the database will become one and stored in a variable then displayed.

> Additional information, Response time is the total amount of time it takes to respond to a request for service (best ex. Per/Transactions).

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
Public MysqlConn As New SqlConnection
Dim tTime As Double
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub SButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SButton.Click
    tTime = 0.0#
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    SelectedRow("SELECT * FROM TRANS_QUEUE WHERE Que_No = " & 1 & "")
End Sub

Private Sub RButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RButton.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub PButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PButton.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


    tTime = tTime + 0.1
    Time.Text = "time =" & tTime
End Sub

Public Sub SelectedRow(ByVal SQCommand As String)
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=BOSS;user=sa;password=pass2017;database=DB_CFSys"
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim SQCmd As New SqlCommand(SQCommand, MysqlConn)
    Dim SQDr As SqlDataReader
    SQDr = SQCmd.ExecuteReader()
    SQDr.Read()
    If SQDr.HasRows Then
        MsgBox(SQDr.Item("Time_Arrive").ToString)
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

[DB Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG5XW.png)

Answer (score 0):

anyway, i solved it thanks to hint provided by Alex Essilfie's answer in the other post [Create a simple timer to count seconds, minutes and hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984831/create-a-simple-timer-to-count-seconds-minutes-and-hours)
.

so here is my answer:

```
 Private Sub SButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SButton.Click
    tTime = 0.0#
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub RButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RButton.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub PButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PButton.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    'MsgBox(GetTime(tTime))
    SelectedRow("SELECT * FROM TRANS_QUEUE WHERE Que_No = " & 1 & "")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick


    tTime = tTime + 0.1
    Time.Text = "time =" & GetTime(tTime)

End Sub

Public Sub SelectedRow(ByVal SQCommand As String)
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=BOSS;user=sa;password=pass2017;database=DB_CFSys"
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim SQCmd As New SqlCommand(SQCommand, MysqlConn)
    Dim SQDr As SqlDataReader
    SQDr = SQCmd.ExecuteReader()
    SQDr.Read()
    If SQDr.HasRows Then
        'MsgBox(SQDr.Item("Time_Arrive").ToString)
        t = TimeSpan.Parse(SQDr.Item("Time_Arrive").ToString)
        t = t + TimeSpan.Parse(GetTime(tTime))
        MsgBox(t.ToString)
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()

End Sub

Public Function GetTime(Time As Integer) As String
    Dim Hrs As Integer  'number of hours   '
    Dim Min As Integer  'number of Minutes '
    Dim Sec As Integer  'number of Sec     '

    'Seconds'
    Sec = Time Mod 60

    'Minutes'
    Min = ((Time - Sec) / 60) Mod 60

    'Hours'
    Hrs = ((Time - (Sec + (Min * 60))) / 3600) Mod 60

    Return Format(Hrs, "00") & ":" & Format(Min, "00") & ":" & Format(Sec, "00")
End Function
```